# dyld: Symbol not found HeapBufferStorage

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to include a framework to my xcode project and I get the following error when trying to run the app:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TMPdCSs18_HeapBufferStorage
  Referenced from: /Users/christiandodier/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EDE17628-655D-422A-846F-C190466A5E17/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/793F7080-6808-4670-80F5-F3A189CB4969/Test.app/Frameworks/hitoeAPI.framework/hitoeAPI
  Expected in: /Users/christiandodier/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EDE17628-655D-422A-846F-C190466A5E17/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/793F7080-6808-4670-80F5-F3A189CB4969/Test.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
 in /Users/christiandodier/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EDE17628-655D-422A-846F-C190466A5E17/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/793F7080-6808-4670-80F5-F3A189CB4969/Test.app/Frameworks/hitoeAPI.framework/hitoeAPI
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is looks to me like you are using the latest Xcode 7.3 with SDK 9.3 and linking with a library that was built with an older SDK.

The libswiftCore.dylib has been updated from Swift 2.1 to Swift 2.2 in 7.3/9.3 and they are not binary compatible.

Try downloading Xcode 7.03 with older SDK or rebuild the hitoeAPI.framework in Xcode 7.3

Comment: Yeah [looks like swift 2.2 came with xcode 7.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions), the previous version of xcode (7.2.1) still featured swift 2.1.1, so one could download [that version of xcode](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.2.1/Xcode_7.2.1.dmg) instead of going all the way back to 7.03